# Ancient rishis had deep infoscience knowledge

Tags: scripture, vedas, shruti

The protection of the correctness of Veda passing from generation to generation already discussed here. However there is an invention that shows pandits already knew important stuff now used in communication systems and information coding. Which Veda was it?

Comment: Restricting the verses to a particular meter (Chanda) acts as a form of parity test. Is this the direction you are looking in? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: Parity is a very important technique. The one used by our ancient brahmarishis is more advanced and truly amazing.

Comment: Hi! You can also self answer your question, if you know answer to it.